# Worklight does not display the Authentication Challenge

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, ibm-mobilefirst

I use my worklight app as a container for a server page. However, the server page prompts a window authentication challenge dialog. So basically when your enter this page, a dialog window would show to ask for your credentials.
It shows on the mobile browser, but does not show inside the app for android and ios.
I did some research. There is only native solution. It seems that authentication pupup does not work with UIWebView.
Does worklight has a solution / workaround for this?
Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if Worklight has something for what you describe, but if you are doing a hybrid application, you can create your own Cordova plugin to use the native solution to your problem. See how here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

If your app is rendering its own content but requires authentication with your server to access data, then you have to look into Worklight's [Security Framework](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_security_framework.html) and [Getting Started](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html) modules.

From a high perspective, you will need to use Worklight's authentication mechanism (like a form based authentication) to collect and authenticate the user before getting access to your server data.

Now if your app is rendering server-generated content (through a WebView, for instance), then you will have to manually implement a mechanism to capture the user credentials and pass it to your server. It will depend on the type of authentication required by your server, and a Cordova plugin (as suggested by Daniel Gonzalez on a comment) might be one way. The Getting Started module [Container for Advanced Pages](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/10_09_Container_for_advanced_pages.pdf) might be helpful (plus [project file](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/ContainerForAdvancedPagesProject.zip))

I hope this helps...